# Unwanted audio delay in Corona SDK

Tags: audio, lua, coronasdk

I am currently making an extremely simple app where when an image is tapped, a sound plays and some text records the amount of clicks. However, I noticed some significant delay in the audio, where it would take half a second for the sound to play after the image is clicked. Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be the case?

```
local function btnTouch(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
    media.playSound( "btnSnd.mp3" )
    score = score + 1
    btnText.text = score
    return true
    end
end

--code
imageBtn:addEventListener("touch", btnTouch)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is probably that the sound needs to be loaded. Try and switch it to audio instead and preload it. Try and see if this gives you the desired result:

```
local buttonSendAudio = audio.loadSound( "btnSnd.mp3")
local function btnTouch(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        audio.play( buttonSendAudio )
        score = score + 1
        btnText.text = score
        return true
    end
end

--code
imageBtn:addEventListener("touch", btnTouch)
```

https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/media/audioSystem/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Worth checking if sound has some silence stored in mp3.
Open it with any audio editor, see sound's waveform.